# Rename 2 similar files with different extension to first file, but keep extensions

Tags: linux, rename

I have sets of .m4v and .srt files in the same directory, but the names only match for the first 3 characters.
How can i rename the .srt files to match the corresponding .m4v files (whilst keeping the .srt extension of course)?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given one of the `.m4v` names in the shell variable `name`, the name of the corresponding `.srt` file is had by trimming `$name` at the first space and adding the `.srt` filename suffix.

This is done with `${name%% *}.srt`. This removes the longest suffix string matching  `*` from `$name` and then adds `.srt` to the end of that result.

The new name for the `.srt` file is `$name`, but with the `.m4v` filename suffix changed to `.srt`.

This is done with `${name%.m4v}.srt`. This removes the (shortest) suffix string matching `.m4v` from `$name`  and then adds `.srt` to the end of that result.

The following is a loop that uses the two parameter substitutions above to rename each `.srt` file given the list of `.mv4` files found in the current directory.  Thes loop additionally lets you know if there is a `.m4v` file without a corresponding `.srt` file, or if the new name for the `.srt` file already exists.

```bash
for name in *.m4v; do
    if [ ! -e "${name%% *}.srt" ]; then
        printf 'Can not find .srt file for "%s"\n' "$name"
        continue
    elif [ -e "${name%.m4v}.srt" ]; then
        printf '.srt file for "%s" already exists\n' "$name"
        continue
    fi >&2

    mv -- "${name%% *}.srt" "${name%.m4v}.srt"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

In `zsh`:

```
for f (???.srt) () {
  (( $# == 1 )) && mv -- $f $1:r.srt
} $f[1,3]?*.m4v(NY2)
```

Which renames the `???.srt` file, copying the `r`oot name of the `m4v` file with the same 3 character prefix as long as there's one any only one such m4v file.